# Ag grid column toolpanel checbox selection event in serverside model

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using server side model in ag-grid, in column tool panel I am showing some fields, when I select a checkbox I need to update the data based on selected fields.when clicking on checkbox not getting to getrows method to update/ I did n't find event for checkbox select and deselect and get their values

I tried using selectionChange but that event is also not triggering